# How to delete an empty tag?

Tags: support, tags

There is a new tag [coupla](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coupla) which is a clear typo of [copula](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copula).  I corrected it in the one post it is used in, but how do I delete the tag itself which is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3788?

Comment: When I have re-tagged all the posts in the past then eventually the tag disappears by itself. I cannot find a definitive link for this behaviour but I suspect if you come back tomorrow all will be well.

Comment: @mdewey is correct: unused tags naturally disappear after a short time.  I prefer leaving such tags as aliases so that in the future they won't be recreated *ab initio*, repeating the whole cycle.  BTW, Peter, because we're discussing things that only diamond mods have access to, this isn't the right place to raise this question: please use the [moderators' chat room.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20/infinite-variance)  By not participating you have been missing a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, the best thing to do in your case is make the misspelled tag a synonym of the correct tag and merge them.  That way, the correct tag will be on the thread, but that misspelling will be automatically mapped to the correct tag in the future.  After all, if one person uses that misspelling, sooner or later someone else will, too.  This should fix the problem forever.  (Users without moderator powers should flag such threads and request this procedure when they come across the same situation.)

To answer your specific question, the SE system automatically culls tags after a while.  If there are no threads associated with a tag, it will be deleted after 24 hours—you don't have to do anything.  If a tag is only on one thread, it will be deleted after 6 months.